# Can I add a new language to the Beautify extension for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autohotkey, js-beautify

I have been trying for a few hours now to add AutoHotKey as a language to the Beautify extension for Visual Studio Code, and am just about to pull my hair out.

Looking at the Overview on the [download page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify) I got the impression that I could add a new language, however, being sort of new to programming in general, the documentation I have been able to find has proven insufficient, and I could be mistaken entirely that custom languages is even a feature.

I have added

```
"beautify.language": {
    "ahk": {
        "type": "ahk",
        "filename": ".ahk"
    }
```

to Visual Studio Code's settings.json.

Furthermore, I have added a file .jsbeautifyrc to my file's directory

```
{
    "ahk": {
        "indent_size": 4,
        "indent_char": " "
    }
}
```

I would like for my file (with the extension .ahk) to be formattable with the settings provided, however, when I try to run Beautify I get "Couldn't determine type to beautify, please choose." and a choice of JS, CSS, or HTML.

I don't know where to go from here, any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Beautify because it doesn't support AutoHotKey as a language. i.e. It only knows Javascript, CSS, or HTML, it doesn't know the syntax for AutoHotKey.

Instead, you should install the AutoHotKey Extension: 
[vscode-autohotkey](https://github.com/stef-levesque/vscode-autohotkey) for Visual Studio Code. This will add AHK Syntax highlighting to Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Syntax highlighting is not the issue. Are you telling me though, that you cannot add a new language for Beautify to format?